# Why is this closed subset of $\mathbb CP^n$ a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, projective-space

Let $\mathbb CP^{n+1}$ be the complex projective space where n is even.

Let S = the subset where $x_0x_1 + x_2x_3 + ... x_{n}x_{n+1} = 0$

> Show that S is a (toplogical) manifold and what is its dimension?

I tried to cover by the usual $U_i$ sets where the $i^{th}$ coordinate is non-zero. But I can't show it is homeomorphic to some $\mathbb C^n$. Some help?

Comment: There's a theorem that says that if $f$ is a submersion then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a sub-manifold. In this case $f(x)=x_0x_1+\cdots+x_nx_{n+1}$ and $y=0$.

Comment: can you provide some links to the proof of that statement?

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person You can search "submersion" in your favourite search engine. This is one of the very first results in differential geometry.